# How to fetch GitHub folders outside of GitHub to display the files inside of a specific folder

Tags: javascript, github, dynamic

I am trying to fetch a GitHub repository and display the files inside of a specific folder, "hacks" (the repository in question is https://github.com/Prodigy-Hacking/ProdigyMathGameHacking). How would I do this in JavaScript, without having to make a copy of the files and constantly have to update them?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the API is here: https://developer.github.com/v4/

Comment: SO is not a good place to ask others do something from scratch for you. Please edit your question and share with us what have you done till now. I suggest please spend some time and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GitHub API REST Client](https://developer.github.com/v3/) (known as v3) it's very simple to use

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/Prodigy-Hacking/ProdigyMathGameHacking
```

will give you everything you can query in that repo, and you will see that's a `contents` path, so trying that with the path:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/Prodigy-Hacking/ProdigyMathGameHacking/contents/hacks
```

and you can then loop through the return array and get each file, but if you really need to get the raw content of a specific file, then, let's assume, for this example we want `/hacks/Character/customName.js`

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/Prodigy-Hacking/ProdigyMathGameHacking/contents/hacks/Character/customName.js

{
  "name": "customName.js",
  "path": "hacks/Character/customName.js",
  "sha": "77b86151fbc3930d5f11e785333f82adbcc33ebf",
  "size": 118,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Prodigy-Hacking/ProdigyMathGameHacking/contents/hacks/Character/customName.js?ref=master",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/Prodigy-Hacking/ProdigyMathGameHacking/blob/master/hacks/Character/customName.js",
  "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Prodigy-Hacking/ProdigyMathGameHacking/git/blobs/77b86151fbc3930d5f11e785333f82adbcc33ebf",
  "download_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Prodigy-Hacking/ProdigyMathGameHacking/master/hacks/Character/customName.js",
  "type": "file",
  "content": "Ly8gQ3VzdG9tIG5hbWUgKENsaWVudCBzaWRlIG9ubHkpLiAoUHV0IHRleHQg\naW4gdGV4dCBoZXJlLikKaGFjay5pbnN0YW5jZS5wcm9kaWd5LnBsYXllci5n\nZXROYW1lID0gKCkgPT4gIlRFWFQgSEVSRSI7Cg==\n",
  "encoding": "base64",
  "_links": {
    "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/Prodigy-Hacking/ProdigyMathGameHacking/contents/hacks/Character/customName.js?ref=master",
    "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/Prodigy-Hacking/ProdigyMathGameHacking/git/blobs/77b86151fbc3930d5f11e785333f82adbcc33ebf",
    "html": "https://github.com/Prodigy-Hacking/ProdigyMathGameHacking/blob/master/hacks/Character/customName.js"
  }
}
```

hitting that `download_url` will give you

```js
// Custom name (Client side only). (Put text in text here.)
hack.instance.prodigy.player.getName = () => "TEXT HERE";
```

it is well explained in [GitHub Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/)

you can now, easily loop through the data at your own like ... remember that you should [authenticate your calls](https://dev.to/gr2m/github-api-authentication-personal-access-tokens-53kd), or you will hit the GitHub limit.